# Integration CKFinder in CKEditor on Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, vue-component, ckeditor5

I'm new to vue.js. Integrated CKEditor successfully but having trouble to integrate CKFinder in it. I'm trying to Import CKFinder in CKEditor component but I'm getting an error.

CKEditor-Vue Component:

```
<template>
    <ckeditor :editor="editor" :value="defaultValue"
              @input="editorInput" :disabled="disabled" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
    import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';
    import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder'

    export default {
        name: "Editor",
        props: {
            defaultValue: String,
            disabled: Boolean
        },
        data() {
            return {
                editor: DecoupledEditor,
                editorConfig: {
                    plugins: [
                        CKFinder
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            editorInput(e) {
                this.$emit('getEditorData', e);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

When I try to import CKFinder it's showing `ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated.`. Screenshot: [image: CKFinder Import Error]

Am I doing anything wrong? Do you have any integration guide or correction on my component?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to import

```
import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder'
```

because it is [already included in the build](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html#installation) of your choice. You only need to [configure it](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html#configuration) and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear like what oleq mean, just make a config under the `editorConfig` like this. You don't need to import it.

```
<script>
    import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';
    import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder'

    export default {
        name: "Editor",
        props: {
            defaultValue: String,
            disabled: Boolean
        },
        data() {
            return {
                editor: DecoupledEditor,
                editorConfig: {
                    plugins: [
                        ckfinder: {
                             uploadUrl:
                        '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',
                             filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/browser',
                             filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/browser?type=Images',
                             filebrowserUploadUrl:'/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
                             filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            editorInput(e) {
                this.$emit('getEditorData', e);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```